# Enviar variable PHP a funcion de dhtmlx gantt

Tags: php, javascript, librería

tengo un diagrama de gantt con **dhtmlx gantt** y he logrado exportarlo a PDF con el siguiente código, mi problema es que quiero pasarle información al header y al footer información que genero en PHP pero no me es posible. Cuando pongo variables de Javascript me funciona bien pero cuando paso una variable de php a una de javascript se congela mi botón. ¿Estoy cometiendo algún error al pasar la variable o no es posible mandarle información desde php?

```
<?php
    $datos='<input type="text" value="este es un input de prueba">';
?>
<script>
    var variableGantPDF="<?php echo $datos; ?>";
</script>
<input value="Exportar a PDF" type="button" onclick='zoomToFit();gantt.exportToPDF({locale: "sp", raw: true, header: "</br></br>aqui va el codigo html de las cosas que se despliegan arriba del gantt", footer: "mi variable:  "+variableGantPDF})'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo tiene un error en el javascript en esta linea

```
var variableGantPDF="<?php echo $datos; ?>";
```

porque al ejecutarlo generaría el siguiente código:

(***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier***)

```
var variableGantPDF="<input type="text" value="este es un input de prueba">";
```

Lo cual es un error porque tenemos una cadena string sin cerrar. Prueba colocandolo de esta manera:

```
var variableGantPDF='<?php echo $datos; ?>';
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por mostrarme mi error, lo coloque a tu manera y me funciono, pero la única diferencia que noto son el tipo de comillas, eso era lo que tenia mal?

Comment: Si las comillas porque en la variable `$datos` del php ya las tenias colocadas en el input y después en el `javascript` cuando haces el echo llenas la variables pero también con las comillas dobles del `javascript`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @AbrilTapia, si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor márcala como aceptada.